# Exit from polling on avahi?

Tags: linux, avahi

I've read the [example code](http://avahi.org/wiki/RunningAvahiClientAsThread) but I can't seem to find the exit condition(s) for the threaded poll.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the threaded loop will be running as long as you don't call: `avahi_threaded_poll_stop(threaded_poll)` from the main loop (or `..._quit` from inside the helper thread) . You may want to do so when the client callback returns `AVAHI_CLIENT_FAILURE`. (see [client exemple](http://avahi.org/download/doxygen/client-browse-services_8c-example.html))

Is that why you asked?